# Combining security rules when specific field is updatable by only certain users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an `issue` document and I want to apply the following restrictions to update it -

1. user must be logged in
2. user is either the creator of that issue or user is a moderator
3. to update the `status` field user must be a moderator

I can implement the first 2 rules with -

```js
allow update: if (isLoggedIn() && (isCreator() || isModerator()));
```

But I'm having a hard time combining proper logic for the 3rd rule with this.

On the front end, I can show/hide the `status` field based on whether the current user is a moderator or not. But how can I enforce this restriction on back end with security rules?

Following is my ruleset -

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
  function isLoggedIn(){
    return request.auth != null;
  }
  
  function isCreator(rsc){
    return request.auth.uid == rsc.data.postedById;
  }
  
  function isModerator(){
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.moderator == true;
  }
  
  function isStatusField(rcs){
    return request.resource.data.diff(rcs.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['status']);
  }
  
    match /issues/{issue} {
      allow read;
      allow create: if isLoggedIn();
      allow update: if (isLoggedIn() && (isCreator() || isModerator()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend framing the rules slightly differently:

1. A moderator on the document can modify any field in it.
2. The creator of the document can modify all fields, except the `status`.

This makes it clearer that you need to split on the user's role earlier on in your condition, and likely leads to something like:

```
allow update: if (isLoggedIn() && (
  isModerator() || (
    isCreator() && !('status' in request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys())
  )
));
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice re-framing. Looks like it should work, but somehow on my end it is denying non-moderator users to update fields other than `status`. I'll look into it and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: The negation of `'status' in request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys()` was expected inside parentheses. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping we'd have enough parentheses without those. :) 
Good to hear you got it working 
Added them in my answer too.

Comment: Just put the negation symbol outside the parentheses - that's how it worked for me :)